# this.props.location.query ends up being undefined in my component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

This issue comes up once in a while in my unit tests (jest). The following output is how `this.props.location` looks like:

```
this.props.location: Object {
  pathname: '/logs',
  search: '?hello=kitty',
  hash: '',
  state: null,
  action: 'POP',
  key: 'zn54se',
  query: undefined } <<< NOTE that i's undefined <<<<<
```

I'm not sure what causing it. Here's how the components are setup:

```
// Logs.jsx:
...
renderToolbar() {
  var generateClassName = (destObj) =>
  {
    console.log("this.props.location:", this.props.location);
  }
  ...

  return <Button to="/logs" className={generateClassName({kind: 'all'})}>All</Button>;
}

render() {
  return <Grid toolbar={this.renderToolbar} />;
}

// Grid.jsx:
...
renderToolbar() {
  return this.props.toolbar ? this.props.toolbar() : '';
},

render() {
  return <div> { this.renderToolbar(); } </div>;
}
```

Here's the route setup (in my test):

```
describe('Logs', function() {
  var ts = (new Date()).valueOf();
  var node;
  beforeEach(function(){

    jest.setMock('myapp/lib/api/request', {});
    node = document.createElement('div');
    path = "/logs?hello=kitty";
    history = createHistory(path);
    routes = <Router history={history}><Route path="/logs" component={Logs} /></Router>;
  });

  it('should render one log entry', function() {
    LogStore.getLogs = jest.genMockFunction().mockReturnValue(
      [ {key: 0, kind: 'transfer', timestamp: ts, conn1name: 'Connector', conn2name: 'Connector2'} ]
    );

    var handler = ReactDOM.render(routes, node);

    expect(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(handler, 'log-entry').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Here's what path is `path = "/logs";`,

Comment: It should still be an empty object. So, I updated `path` that I pass into `createHistory()` to include `?hello=kitty` and still see the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, `jest` was mocking `qs` module which is a dependency of `react-router` use to generate a query object. This is why it was ending up undefined.

To fix it, I added `/qs` to my `jest` settings in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
        "/qs",
        ...
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked out for me in unit test

`<Router basename="">
        <Switch>
          <Route history={history} path="/">
            <MyApp/>
          </Route>
        </Switch> 
</Router>`

where history is defined as follows

`import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: '/'
});`